# After using LayoutInflator to add a new layout to the current layout, views cannot be modified

Tags: android

I have code like this:

```
        FrameLayout containerFrame = (FrameLayout) onThisActivity.findViewById(viewIDtoShowIndicatorOn);

        onThisActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.su_activity_indicator, containerFrame);
```

Then I try to access a view inside the layout:su_activity_indicator I just added like this:

```
            suAnimatedImage = (SUAnimatedImage) onThisActivity.findViewById(R.id.loadinganimationView);

            suAnimatedImage.setImageDrawable(bt);
```

Does all this seem correct to all of you guys?  I checked that it found everything and no nulls, but it never applies the image on screen.

Comment: even setting colour does not have an effect setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't set your inflated view to `onThisActivity`

```
 onThisActivity = LayoutInflator.from(containerFrame.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.su_activity_indicator, containerFrame, false);
```

Comment: He actually did, since the method he is using inflate directly the layout inside the root

Comment: But does it then add the inflated view to the container calling `onThisActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(...)`?

Comment: It did inflate and it did show up inside the target Layout, is just that after that, I cannot modify the views inside it even though findViewById finds it.